# Angular 4 + Webpack - How can I support a relative PublicPath

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm unable to know the PublicPath at compile time, so it needs to be set dynamically at runtime for all associated resources.

Compile time example:

```
output: {
  publicPath: './test'
}
```

index.html...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./test/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./test/vendor.js">
```

SO THE PUBLICPATH IS PREFIXED TO THE SCRIPT SRC LOCATIONS, AND EVERYTHING WORKS OK...

Now, to do this at runtime seems to require **webpack_public_path** to be set within the Angular entry point (main.ts). So, for example I've set...

(https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration)

```
declare var  __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = './test';
```

But this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: And this can't be done using `<base href="/test">` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not... index.html contains <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js">, so still refers to the web server root, so unable to find file.